# Using datetime as ticks in Matplotlib

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, matplotlib

I'm basically trying to plot a graph where the x axis represent the month of the year. The data is stored in a numpy.array, with dimensions `k x months`. Here it follows a minimal example (my data is not this crazy):

```
import numpy
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cmap = plt.get_cmap('Set3')
colors = [cmap(i) for i in numpy.linspace(0, 1, len(complaints))]

data = numpy.random.rand(18,12)
y = range(data.shape[1])

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 7), dpi=200)
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    plt.plot(y, data[i,:], color=colors[i], linewidth=5)
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5)) 
plt.xticks(numpy.arange(0, 12, 1))
plt.xlabel('Hour of the Day')
plt.ylabel('Number of Complaints')
plt.title('Number of Complaints per Hour in 2015')
```

[image]

I'd like to have the `xticks` as strings instead of numbers. I'm wondering if I have to create a list of strings, manually, or if there is another way to *translate* the numbers to months. I have to do the same for weekdays, for example.

I've been looking to these examples:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/finance_demo.html
http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo2.html

But I'm not using `datetime`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an alternative plotting method `plot_date`, which you might want to use if your independent variable are `datetime` like, instead of using the more general `plot` method:

```
import datetime
data = np.random.rand(24)

#a list of time: 00:00:00 to 23:00:00
times = [datetime.datetime.strptime(str(i), '%H') for i in range(24)]

#'H' controls xticklabel format, 'H' means only the hours is shown
#day, year, week, month, etc are not shown
plt.plot_date(times, data, fmt='H')
plt.setp(plt.gca().xaxis.get_majorticklabels(),
         'rotation', 90)
```

[image]

The benefit of it is that now you can easily control the density of xticks, if we want to have a tick every hour, we will insert these lines after `plot_date`:

```
##import it if not already imported
#import matplotlib.dates as mdates
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the plot_date() method. Does this only work if you already have the rounded hour in the x data? The data I'm working with doesn't, and using the mdate.HourLocator() ends up with no tick labels at all.

Comment: Since the question show in google result, it's worth to point that plot_date will/is deprecated now.

Answer (score 21):

Althought [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35467293/6188901) works well, for this case you can avoid defining your own `FuncFormatter` by using the pre-defined ones from `matplotlib` for dates, by using `matplotlib.dates` rather than `matplotlib.ticker`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Define time range with 12 different months:
# `MS` stands for month start frequency 
x_data = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=12, freq='MS') 
# Check how this dates looks like:
print(x_data)
y_data = np.random.rand(12)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x_data, y_data)
# Make ticks on occurrences of each month:
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
# Get only the month to show in the x-axis:
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b'))
# '%b' means month as locale’s abbreviated name
plt.show()
```

Obtaining:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '2018-03-01', '2018-04-01',
           '2018-05-01', '2018-06-01', '2018-07-01', '2018-08-01',
           '2018-09-01', '2018-10-01', '2018-11-01', '2018-12-01'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')
```

[image: Plot showing abbreviated months on the x-axis]

Answer (score 5):

You can still use formatters to format your results in the way you want. For example, to have month names printed, let us first define a function taking an integer to a month abbreviation:

```
def getMonthName(month_number):
    testdate=datetime.date(2010,int(month_number),1)
    return testdate.strftime('%b')
```

Here, I have created an arbitrary date with the correct month and returned that month. Check [the datetime documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for available format codes if needed. If that is always easier than just setting a list by hand is another question. Now let us plot some monthly testdata:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
import numpy as np

x_data=np.arange(1,12.5,1)
y_data=x_data**2 # Just some arbitrary data
plt.plot(x_data,y_data)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mtick.FixedLocator(x_data)) # Set tick locations
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FuncFormatter(lambda x,p:getMonthName(x)))
plt.show()
```

The message here is that you can use `matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter` to use any function to obtain a tick label. The function takes two arguments (value and position) and returns a string.