# Change the datetime xticks frequency - matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, series

I'm practising in machine learning and i currently use the following dataset.
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Occupancy+Detection+

I would like to line plot the temperature feature based on datetime.

I have already converted the dataset to a pandas series dataframe and then i pass the series (datetime, temperature) to my plot.

My problem is that in my x axis i have only 1 tick per day, and i would like to see 1 tick per hour.

```
ts_train.plot()
importer.plt.show()
```

Sorry but i'm completely unexperienced in this topic.

Comment: See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465409/using-datetime-as-ticks-in-matplotlib) for plotting hourly ticks. You probably need to use `plt.plot()` to be able to use matplotlib tickers, like the `HourLocator`, instead of the `df.plot()` wrapper.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest , i'll take a look right now!

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks, thad did the trick, if you want you can post the answer so i can accept it!

Comment: Well no. If the linked answer answers your question, one would mark this as duplicate instead of answering it again.

Comment: Ok! sounds fair, thanks anyway.