# Using datetime to set xticks of matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a function that takes a month and year and I want to set the xticks of a plot to the month and year that is inputted.

For example if user enters 5 as the month and 2019 as the year I want to make the first xtick 5/2018, the second one 6/2018, and so on. If it reaches 12/2018, the next tick should be 1/2019.

I was reading about datetime but I'm not sure how I would use it for this problem.

I tried this but it doesn't work and I'm pretty sure this is not the way to tackle this.

```
cityPlot(self, year, month):

   myDates = [datetime(int(year), month, 1]
   plt.plot(myDates)
```

Comment: where is you code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[matplotlib.pyplot.xticks](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) is probably what are you looking for. You should look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465409/using-datetime-as-ticks-in-matplotlib) too