# Date in form of yyyy-mm in x axis for line plot pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

How to get dates in yyyy-mm format. I checked few link , but couldn't get the result for my dataframe.

df

```
    [IN]data2=df.ix[:,2]
    [IN]data2 #data2 is series object now, since it is slice of df
    [OUT]
    Date
    2015-01-01     3.2
    2015-02-01     4.6
    2015-03-01     5.9
    ..........................
    2018-01-01    11.3
    2018-02-01    13.4
    Name: Col2, dtype: float64
```

My dataframe has only one value corresponding to each month-year combination(for eg Jan 2015 will have only one value, Feb2015 will hav only one value and so on)

Date is index for dataframe df. I need the x axis in form of yyyy-mm for the command **data2.plot()**

**Current output**(command data2.plot())

[image]

**EXPECTED OUTPUT** (Ignore the shape of the graph, just focus on x axis) (I need this ouput on entering data2.plot())

[image]

Some code before data2.plot() was deleted and we are unable to retrieve the same, hence I want that we should be able to get the output after typing data2.plot()

Comment: Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465409/using-datetime-as-ticks-in-matplotlib/53885396#53885396). You may need to use `'%Y-%m'` instead of `%b` (see [this table](https://strftime.org/) for reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct some sample data and extract the sample Series `data2` as in your question:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.random.rand(20, 3), 
    index=pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01', freq='MS', periods=20))
data2 = df.iloc[:, 2]
```

Assuming you plot your dataframe explicitly with `matplotlib` like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(data2.index, data2)
```

You can set the ticks with the `matplotlib.dates` module:

```
import matplotlib as mpl

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.dates.MonthLocator(interval=3))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))

ax.tick_params(rotation=30, axis='x')  # rotate xticks
```

`interval=3` selects every third month, the date formatter `%Y-%m` produces the `YYYY-MM` format.

More on date formatting can be found in the documentation of the [`matplotlib.dates`](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html?highlight=dateformatter) module and specifically for locating months in [`matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html?highlight=dateformatter#matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator).

Plotting with the pandas plotting interface (f.i. `df.plot()`) may require other date formatting methods, since the conversion to axis-units is handled differently in pandas. Thus I'd always recommend sticking to explicitly using matplotlib when plotting with dates to get reproducible results.

Comment: there are many columns in df. I am working on series objects for a reason. There is a code after this plotting which requires me to work with series objects'

Comment: please `work on data2` only where `data2=df.ix[:,2]`

Comment: I replaced `df` in the plotting function with `data2`. But since `ix` is deprecated and not available in current versions of `pandas`, I replaced it with the newer `iloc`.