# Plotting from pandas makes date stick together

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm graphing the COVID cases and deaths with respect to time, but the dates seem to be overlapping.
Code is below:

```
data = pd.read_csv(filename)

data["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Date"], format = "%Y/%m/%d")
axes = data.plot.bar(rot=0, subplots=True, x="Date",
                     y=["Cases", "Deaths"], lw=0)

axes[1].legend(loc=2)

plt.show()
```

What went wrong, and how can I fix it?

Program Output-

[image]

Comment: you have too many dates. Maybe use `rot=90` instead of `rot=0`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using datetime as ticks in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465409/using-datetime-as-ticks-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add rotation with:

```
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could one of two things:

- Use fewer dates on the x-axis.
  Select the dates you want as ticks on the x-axis as an array.
  Pass this array to `axes[1].set_xticks`.
- Set the rotation of the labels to an angle that doesn't cause the overlap.
  `axes[1].set_xtick_labels(axes[1].get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)`

Refer:

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/axes_api.html#the-axes-class

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text